# Center horizontally between 2 items in AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm struggling to center an image between other two images so it's always in the middle, mo matter what device you're using. I want to center the "clock" icon What's the best way to achieve this?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Embed all 3 views into parent view (possibly already done).
2. Center "clock" vertically in container.

Comment: Actually, what worked for me was creating a view without a width that extends from the brown box to the orange one and setting the clock to align with the vertical center of that view

Comment: I meant almost the same.